# Selecting multiple table values and binding the data into multiple grids

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I have multiple tables .

I have created one stored procedure where I am selecting the table values.

like

```
  create proc myProc
  as
        select col1, col2, col3 from table1
        select cola, colb, colc from table2
        select colp, colq, colr from table3
        select colx, coly, colz from table4
```

I am using LINQ to retrieve the Data. So Using Linq I am calling the stored procedure.
So I ll get the table values in the C# Code the table values.

so in my UI i have 4 gridviews.

I want split the output values into four source and bind it to the grid.

So Please give me some example and source which ll help me the best.

Thanking you in Advance

Umakanta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these blogs, it may help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/02/04/linq-to-sql-returning-multiple-result-sets.aspx

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/05/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results-imultipleresults.aspx